# Trane heat pump compressor and outside fan do not start after being idle

Tags: pump, heat, pressure

Trane 4dcy4060a  in heat mode,  after being idle for a while the thermostat calls for heat - the indoor fan starts but the compressor and outside fan do not.  initially  (a couple months ago) i could push on the contactor and the unit would run and keep running and the problem occurred maybe once or twice a week - mostly when the weather is 30 - 35.   recently the contactor would not stay closed - no voltage on the coil.  I determined that if i tap the high pressure cutoff switch the unit starts up and keeps running- until next time this happens.   It has become more frequent - and is now happening more frequently  - almost daily.  if I tap the high temp switch when it is not running it will run for maybe 15 seconds and stop; then tapping the high pressure switch starts it and it keeps running.  Is the problem the high pressure cutoff is faulty or could there be some other problem?  seems odd it would be open when the unit has been idle.

Comment: I'm no HVAC expert, but it sounds like the switch is sticking and needs to be repaired/replaced.

Comment: The high pressure cutoff could be doing its job and shutting the system down. When compressible gas type equipment starts failing this is the time to have serviced. Pushing it until it no longer works can fry the compressor as one possibility or a simple high pressure safety is going bad. but blindly going at it can cost in the long run. High pressure could be the reason it shutdown yes even after a while of running   Many systems have a manual reset for high pressure.

Answer (score 1):

I think I know what is going on (mostly).  the unit was running hot and it sometimes tripped when it stopped he overpressure or had a pressure spike as it turned off which tripped it.  I suspect the switch does not untrip once the unit sits and the pressure drops. tapping the switch reset it.  The reason the unit was running hot is that over time a mold/moss/dust layer had grown over most of the air handler; this was plugging the gaps between the fins and severely reducing the heat transfer efficiency.   I cleaned this off 5 days ago and thus far have not had to tap the high pressure switch.  One thing I cannot explain is that in my initial troubleshooting tapping the high temperature cutoff switch also started the unit but it only ran about 15 seconds and shut down; then tapping high pressure switch would start it.